# Overriding Core Blocks

Tags: magento

I'm try to overriding Mage_Core_Block_Messages
I'm create module
Mycompany_Core.xml and save in path app/etc/modules/Mycompany_Core.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
    <modules>
       <Mycompany_Core>
          <active>true</active>
          <codepool>local</codepool>
      </Mycompany_Core>
    </modules>
 </config>
```

next I was create in app/code/local/Mycompany/Core/Block/Messages.php

```
class Mycompany_Core_Block_Messages extends Mage_Core_Block_Messages
{
//update method
}
```

and add config.xml in app/code/local/Mycompany/Core/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Core>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Mycompany_Core>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <core>
                   <rewrite>
                        <messages>Softdk_Core_Block_Messages</messages>
                    </rewrite>
            </core>
        </blocks>
     </global>
</config>
```

But i don't see any result on frontend, I'm wonder where I'm make mistake.
Thx for help.

Comment: Try <codePool> with P not p

Comment: Did you clear your xml cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that caught my eye.

1.) In your module's registration file, it should be `codePool` and not `codepool` (as also said by David in comments)

2.) What is `Softdk`? If that is the name of your new module, then replace `Mycompany` with `Softdk` everywhere in your module.

Clear cache and voila!

Comment: thx for advice, I changed my mistake  but still, I dont see any result

Comment: if you've cleared the cache then it should work now. try just echoing hi or something (rather than complex code) in your new block to test it's working or not.

Comment: I created new namespace module and all work very well. But i saw that module in old namespace dont show up in PA->System->Configuration->Advanced, probably that was reason of my problem, thx for help

Comment: @user1958112 Glad to know it worked. May be in old namespace you had something silly that went wrong. Don't forget to mark answer accepted if it helped ;)